# Handle sync XHR connection errors

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jscript, wsh

I've been searching and can't find any documentation on the matter: How do I handle connection/network related errors when using a Microsoft provided XMLHttpRequest interface to make a synchronous HTTP request.

I'm working under wscript, making an HTTP request wrapper and am wondering how I would handle differing **connection/network errors** *(opposed to server-response-reported errors)* for an HTTP request using an XMLHttpRequest interface.

To clarify, not only do I want to know if a connection/network error occurred but also how to determine what sort of error occurred so different errors would result in different handling. An example would be differing between a `connection timeout` error, `connection refused` error and an `dns resolve` error

```
// httpObj is a valid Microsoft/ActiveX provided XMLHttpRequest object name
function () {

    var request = new ActiveXObject(httpObj);
    request.open(this.httpMethod, this.httpUrl, false);
    request.timeout = this.httpTimeout;
    request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    request.send(this.httpData);

    // How would I handle connection/network-related errors?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I've never used ActiveX requests, but I assume they work like `XMLHttpRequest`; if I am wrong, I will happily delete this answer.)*

If the script was able to read an HTTP error response from the server, the `status` property of the request object will be set to an HTTP error code (`404`, `500`, etc.) and the `statusText` property will be set to a description of the HTTP error.

Otherwise, the `status` property will be `0`, indicating either a network failure or a lack of cross-origin CORS permission.

```
function () {
    ...
    request.send(this.httpData);

    if(request.status == 0) {
        // no response from server, error or otherwise
    }
    if(request.status == 404) {
        // there was a response from the server; it was a 404
    }
}
```

The XHR API does not expose any way to distinguish between types of network errors. The ActiveX object may have some way to do it, but I don't know what it would be, if it exists.

Comment: I'm not looking to handle response-status errors(Errors retruned via the server) but solely connection issues

Comment: How do I differ between a connection timeout out, and a DNS-resolve error, for example?

Comment: @SReject I thought you wanted to distinguish HTTP error response from network errors, but I see from your edit that you actually want to distinguish different types of connection errors. This cannot be done using the XHR API, which does not distinguish between types of network errors. It may be possible using some proprietary ActiveX behavior, but I don't know how, if it's possible at all.

Comment: Just a quick note; There is little difference between ActiveX XHR and the XHR api as the interface was, originally, an MS/IE/ActiveX invention.

Comment: I'm holding off accepting this answer in-case there is an unknown proprietary interface/behavior that a user may report. If no one else answers, I'll accept your answer.